# jquery target this instance of a button after clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, if-statement

I have a button I want to refer back to inside of an if statement, so I can target an element inside of the button's sibling.

```
$(function() {
$('button').click(function() {
        var clickedbtn = $(this);
        if (clickedbtn.closest('.container-destination').find('.slider-display').hasClass('open')) {
            alert('it is open already');
        }
         else if (clickedbtn.closest('.container-destination').find('.slider-display').hasClass('closed')) {
            alert('it is closed');
            $('.slider-display.open').slideUp();
            $('.slider-display.open').addClass('closed');
            $('.slider-display.open').removeClass('open');


            clickedbtn.closest('container-destination').find('slider-display').addClass('open');
            clickedbtn.closest('container-destination').find('slider-display').slideDown();
         }
});
```

});

Comment: Please share your HTML markup

Comment: Also, notice your last two lines are missing class selection (i.e. container-destination should be .container-destination and same with slider-display)

Answer (score 0):

You already refer back to the button several times and assigned it to a variable in this line:

```
var clickedbtn = $(this);
```

Therefore you can refer to the button using clickedbtn

Comment: For persistence this should be declared outside of the `.click()` handler.

Comment: Tom I can't see how your post answers the question!!

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, I mean the variable declared outside, but setting it inside the handler function. This way `$(this)` will reference the element (i.e. button). If the button doesn't need to be referenced outside of the function, then yes, my point is moot. _person I replied to deleted their comment_

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the variable outside of the event then assign the clicked instance to the variable inside it like :

```
$(function() {
    var clickedbtn;

  $('button').click(function() {
    clickedbtn = $(this);
    var sliderDisplay = clickedbtn.closest('.container-destination').find('.slider-display');

    if ( sliderDisplay.hasClass('open') ) {
      alert('it is open already');
    } else if ( sliderDisplay.hasClass('closed') ) {
      alert('it is closed');

      $('.slider-display.open').slideUp().addClass('closed').removeClass('open');
      sliderDisplay.addClass('open').slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```